# Merging class panels with SGPANEL for SAS

Tags: plot, sas, sgplot

Suppose I have a data set with class variable with 4 levels: A, B, C and D. If I want to creater four series plots in SAS Studio I can run the following code using `proc sgpanel`.

```
proc sgpanel data = name;
panelby class;
series X = var1 Y = var2 / group = some_factor;
run;
```

How can modify this code to instead create 2 panels where the first panel has the graphs of both A and B and the second C and D? A naive solution would be to add a "dummy" 0-1 variable to the data set and using `panelby dummy`. However I was hoping for a more elegant solution!

Edit: To clarify I want to have different graphs for A and B in the same panel, not combine data into one graph.

[image: Graphs from the question]

Comment: Will you use GROUP= on the series statement?  Will need a new variable for GROUP?

Comment: Yes I will use the group statement. Let me add that to the code

Comment: Can you show an example using the `dummy` what the resulting sgpanel would be like?  Preferably providing some data, or using `sashelp.class` or `sashelp.prdsale` or similar to get runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming to combine the A/B and C/D into one series each, then this is straightforward.

Using this `sashelp.class` example as the base:

```
proc sgpanel data=sashelp.class;
panelby age;
series x=height y=weight;
run;
```

We create a format that combines the class values in whatever fashion is preferred:

```
proc format;
  value agegroupf
  11-13="Younger"
  14-16="Older"
  ;
quit;
```

Then apply the format.

```
proc sgpanel data=sashelp.class;
format age agegroupf.;
panelby age;
series x=height y=weight;
run;
```

This won't show separate plots for the individual class values on the panel; if that's desired, then `group` could be used with a second class variable (an identical, but second, variable).  However, if `group` is already being used, as in the updated question, it might be complicated to implement this.  Separate `series` statements could be used to show each, but this is perhaps additionally complex.

Here's one way to do the overlaid groups - just copying `age` to `age2`.

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  age2 = age;
run;

proc sgpanel data=class;
format age agegroupf.;
panelby age;
series x=height y=weight/group=age2;
run;
```

I think that in GTL you might be able to do it without actually creating a second variable, but I don't think it's possible in regular SGPanel.

Comment: Sorry, this not what I want. I want to have the series of A and the series of B to be two distinct graphs in the same window/panel. I am not looking to pool the observations themselves

Comment: When you same in the same panel, do you mean overlapping (so, one single axis pair), or do you mean you want still 4 graphs, but "paired" in one column A/B with two pairs of axes, and in one column C/D with two pairs of axes?